# change language on main index.html with reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, multilingual

I'm working on a website and i'm trying to make the site multilanguage. on my index.html I have two title, one in english and another in portuguese.

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <title > EN </title>
    <title lang = "pt-PT"> PT </title>

  </head>
```

So in default language is english and I want to change it to portuguese if the language of the browser becomes portuguese. I already changed the browser in poruguese, but the language is still in english

I'm still new on this and I just wanna know if theres some code or something that can help me resolve this code.

Comment: Hi Fabio, I don't understand the issue you are having, do you need to change the title of the page to reflect the selected language? if so you can just manipulate the DOM by using document.title = '...'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet), which helps you put content in the `<head>` by using react code.
Put this in your root component.

```
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"

const siteLanguage = 'pt-PT'
```

In your render

```
 return (
    ...
    <Helmet htmlAttributes={{
        lang: siteLanguage,
        }} 
    ><title lang={siteLanguage}>PT</title>
    </ Helmet>
    ...
    )
```

Portuguese language code can be 'pt', 'pt-BR' or 'pt-PT'

Comment: hey it worked. thanks for showing me the react-helmet @knada